# how to Shorten this code or how to correct this code

Tags: python, python-2.7

Could you help me by shortening this code? I hope this is possible because I see it too redundant but I don't know how to avoid the repetition. I tried by creating two lists with even letters and odd letters (so basically by creating a new code), but then I don't know how to go on. This is the code:
Basically this is a function that has to check whether the input string has alternated vowels and consonants, like the word 'laser'.It has to return true if the string is alternating vowels and consonants, false in the other case(example: 'loss').
The other code I tried to create was this one:
The problem with the second code is that it returns me true for 'loss' and 'pair' (but they should be false) and 'laser' and 'p' true (as it should be)
and 'play' false (as it should be). How can i correct my error in the second code?

Comment: Won't it be much easier to check `even_letters` and `old_letters` separately and see if one of them are all vowels and another are all consonants?

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: @ ve98 I have posted an answer that correctly does what you are asking.

Comment: This looks a lot like a job for NFA (Nondeterministic finite-state automata.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iterating through each letter, just check two things:

1. The current letter **IS** a vowel and the next letter **IS NOT**.
2. The current letter **IS NOT** a vowel and the next letter **IS**.

You can do that like so:

```
def is_alternating(s):
    s = s.lower()

    vowels = 'aeiou'

    for index, letter in enumerate(s[1:]):
        if letter in vowels and (s[index] not in vowels) or letter not in vowels and (s[index] in vowels):
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True

print(is_alternating("Laser"))
print(is_alternating("Loss"))
print(is_alternating("Pair"))
print(is_alternating("Racecar"))

# Prints:
# True
# False
# False
# True
```

This will also work by getting each letter at an even and odd index and using `all()`:

```
def is_alternating(s):
    s = s.lower()
    vowels = "aeiou"
    even = [s[i] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
    odd = [s[i] for i in range(1, len(s), 2)]
    return (
    (all(letter in vowels for letter in even) and all(letter not in vowels for letter in odd)) or 
    (all(letter in vowels for letter in odd) and all(letter not in vowels for letter in even))
    )


print(is_alternating("Laser"))
print(is_alternating("Loss"))
print(is_alternating("Pair"))
print(is_alternating("Racecar"))
```

The second solution is essentially saying:

> `even` is every letter in `s` with an **even** index
>
> `odd` is every letter in `s` with an **odd** index
>
> The `all()` statement checks the following:
>
> 1.) Every **even** indexed letter **IS** in vowels and every **odd** indexed number **is NOT**
>
> OR
>
> 2.) Every **odd** indexed letter **IS** in vowels and every **even** indexed letter **IS NOT**

Comment: I am checking now :D

Comment: Thanks a lot :DDDDDDD

Comment: You're welcome. I also added another method of doing it by splitting the word by even and odd indexes and using `all()` instead of an if statement.

Comment: What is doing the second solution? It says '<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000A8BB9D8>'

Comment: Mind the parenthesis on the second solution. I put them on their own lines as to make the huge return statement a little easier to read. It should be returning either `True` or `False`

Comment: So how should I correct that? Sorry but I don't understand where I have to eliminate the parenthesis. I eliminate the parenthesis that include both the all but it gives me an error

Comment: As long as it's the same as the solution it should work. Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Python 2.7 as i said in tags

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't notice you were using Python 2. I had only tested it in Python 3.6. So I cannot say if the second solution will work for a version below 3. The first solution shouldn't be version specific.

Comment: Oh I see.Don't worry, it's okay. The first one works properly. So thanks again. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158796/discussion-between-darkwidow98-and-jebby).